# fill and overlay do not work well together

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, overlays, tikzmark

In trying to answer the question in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/626011/define-another-command-like-aboxed-but-with-a-different-colorbox) with `tikzmark`, it seems that `[overlay]` and `\fill` are not good enough to use simultaneously.
I have a question - see in the below code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
I want to decorate some math formulae with \verb|tikzmark| of TikZ. For the \verb|\draw| command, it is fine!   
\begin{align*}
\tikzmarknode{F1}{F(p)}&=\tikzmarknode{F2}{\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-pt} e^{at}\,dt}\\[2mm]
&=\dfrac{1}{p-a}.
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[magenta] (F1.north west)+(-.2,.4) rectangle ($(F2.south east)+(.2,-.15)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
For the \verb|\fill| command, there are some tricks like this
\begin{align*}
\tikzmarknode{G1}{G(p)}&\tikzmarknode{G2}{=\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-pt} \cos(at)\,dt}\\[2mm]
&=\dfrac{p}{p^2+a^2}.
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[cyan!50] 
(G1.north west)+(-.2,.4) rectangle ($(G2.south east)+(.2,-.2)$);
\path
(G1) node{$G(p)$}
(G2) node{$=\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-pt}\cos(at)\,dt$};
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
or like this
\begin{align*}
\tikzmarknode{H1}{H(p)}&\tikzmarknode{H2}{=\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-pt} \sin(at)\,dt}\\[2mm]
&=\dfrac{a}{p^2+a^2}.
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[fill=yellow,opacity=.5] 
(H1.north west)+(-.2,.4) rectangle ($(H2.south east)+(.2,-.2)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
However, both of these tricks are not good.

I expect the \verb|\fill| command works well as the \verb|\draw| command in the above situations. Is any way to do that?
\end{document}
```

**Update:** Based on a previous answer by Andrew Stacey, I use `tikzmark` instead of `tikzmarknode`, and put the `tikzpicture` with `\fill` before the math formula to be filled.

[image]

```
% based on a previous answer by Andrew Stacey 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{align*}
\tikzmark{F1}F(p)&=\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-pt} e^{at}\,dt \tikzmark{F2}\\[2mm]
&=\dfrac{1}{p-a}.
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[magenta] (pic cs:F1)+(-.2,-.5) rectangle ($(pic cs:F2)+(.2,.65)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[2]
% This tikzpicture (with \fill) must go before the math formula
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[fill=yellow,rounded corners] (pic cs:G1)+(-.2,-.5) rectangle ($(pic cs:G2)+(.2,.65)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{align*}
\tikzmark{G1}{G(p)}&={\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-pt} \cos(at)\,dt}\tikzmark{G2}\\[2mm] 
&=\dfrac{p}{p^2+a^2}.
\end{align*}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure and can't test it right now but did you try to write the `tikzpicture` before the text to be decorated. It should place the fill under the text.

Comment: Nope! if we write `tikzpicture` before the text to be decorated, the error happends, like this "No shape name `H1` is known" (this is reasonable, right?)

Comment: Because you are using tikzmarknode, then the full node isn't available until after the definition.  The underlying tikzmark is, but that just gives you one point. So, you could place tikzmarks at opposite corners of the node which could then be used beforehand, or you could use the `save node` key on the tikzmarknode to make it available earlier in the text.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Could you give an answer in details? I tried using `tikzmark` as you suggested, but no success!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to `\fill` the rectangle correctly, the `tikzpicture` that defines the rectangle needs to occur *before* the equation is typeset.  This means that the coordinates need to be available before they are defined.  Fortunately, this is relatively straightforward: they need to be written out to a file and read back in on the next compilation.

Tikzmarks already have this capability, so using tikzmarks for the coordinates makes it work.  The slight irritation is that the coordinates needed to define the rectangle aren't the tikzmarks created by the tikzmarknode, so we use another tikzpicture after the equation to determine the coordinates to be saved.

The tikzmark library defines another method that can be used here for saving the information about nodes to an external file and reading them back in at an appropriate juncture.  This is the `save node` key.  There is a catch with this, though, which is that when a `\tikzmarknode` is defined in math mode then actually many nodes are defined to ensure that the node text is set in the correct math style.  The node name that is saved is not then the tikzmarknode name that is passed in.

This feels like something that should be fixed, so I'll look into it.  In the meantime, since the tikzmarknodes are defined in display style, the saved names will be `<name>-d`.a

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/629644/86}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark,backgrounds}

% Load in the saved node information from previous runs.
\tikzset{
  restore nodes from file,
}

\begin{document}

In this version, we use the fact that \verb|tikzmark|s are always available prior to their declaration in the document.
So we put tikzmarks at the corners of the desired rectangle.
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\fill[cyan!50] 
(pic cs:Gnw)+(-.2,.4) rectangle ($(pic cs:Gse)+(.2,-.2)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{align*}
\tikzmarknode{G1}{G(p)}&\tikzmarknode{G2}{=\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-pt} \cos(at)\,dt}\\[2mm]
&=\dfrac{p}{p^2+a^2}.
\end{align*}
%
This is the tikz picture that puts the tikzmarks at the rectangle's corners.
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\tikzmark{Gnw}{(G1.north west)}
\tikzmark{Gse}{(G2.south east)}
\end{tikzpicture}

In this version, we use the \verb+save node+ facility of the tikzmark library.
There's a slight hitch in that when a \verb|\tikzmarknode| is defined in maths mode then actually quite a lot of nodes are created and they are all saved.
Those nodes have names derived from the given name and normally the one that is actually used is aliased to the given name.
However, that aliasing happens when the node is defined so if we want to use it beforehand then we need to refer to the actual name.
This might get fixed in later versions.
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[fill=yellow] 
(H1-d.north west)+(-.2,.4) rectangle ($(H2-d.south east)+(.2,-.2)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{align*}
\tikzmarknode[save node]{H1}{H(p)}&\tikzmarknode[save node]{H2}{=\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-pt} \sin(at)\,dt}\\[2mm]
&=\dfrac{a}{p^2+a^2}.
\end{align*}
However, both of these tricks are not good.

I expect the \verb|\fill| command works well as the \verb|\draw| command in the above situations. Is any way to do that?
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed! Looks like a cheat but works fine. I would definitely know more about the `save node` and `restore node` options because I can't really figure them out from the documentation.

Comment: @SebGlav I'm on a mobile device at the moment so using overleaf, which isn't working properly with the save node stuff.  When I get to a computer, I'll add a solution using save node.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thanks! It works well! I am studying Why did you write `pic cs:` in `(pic cs:Gse) rectangle (pic cs:Gnw)`. Can it be more simple like `(Gse) rectangle (Gnw)` ? Anyway, I am waiting for your full answer.

Comment: It doesn't work with a direct adress like you suggested. The `pic cs:` is precisely the command that makes the picture remind of the `tikzmark` position. Direct adressing is working with `tikzmarknode`, though.

Comment: I've expanded on my answer slightly.  The `save node` feature will probably need the most recent version of the tikzmark library, available from `https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark`

Comment: @AndrewStacey I added in my question: `\tikzmark` instead of `\tikzmarknode`. I suggest adding that example of draw/fill a math formula in the documentation of `tikzmark`

Comment: Sounds like a good plan - I like using examples that have come from things people have actually tried to do.