# How to render a rotated rectangle on certain cells of a table?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, graphics, diagrams, rounded-corners

I want to render a rotated rectangle over certain cells on the table. Each cell of the table contains only one digit. How to achieve this using Latex? [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!! Form example (it should be many more similar drawings in this site): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631467/color-diagonal-of-a-matrix

Comment: Maybe have a look at the `nicematix` package.

Answer (score 5):

It heavily depends on how you would like to create the table, but you could use purely Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix[
            matrix of nodes, 
            draw, 
            inner sep=0pt,
            every node/.style={
                circle, 
                inner sep=0pt, 
                align=center,
                text width=1em, 
                text height=0.8em, 
                text depth=0.2em,
                font=\sffamily
            }] (m) {
            1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
        };
        \node[
            inner sep=0pt,
            draw=red, 
            thick,
            rounded corners=0.5em, 
            rotate fit=45, 
            fit={(m-2-2) (m-5-5)}] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

$\begin{NiceMatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\CodeAfter
    \tikz 
       \node [ 
               inner sep=2.5pt,
               draw=red, 
               thick,
               rounded corners=5pt, 
               rotate fit=45, 
               fit = {(2-2) (5-5)}
             ] {} ;
\end{NiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]